# How to find sysfs directory for a specific device?

Tags: udev, sysfs

I have an input class device (accelerometer) bound to a driver which exposes sysfs attributes that I need to access from userland.  Using a udev rule, I have provided an alias that unambiguously identifies my device, i.e. `ll /dev/input` yields:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May 18 13:47 accelerometer0 -> event0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 May 18 13:47 by-path
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  64 May 18 13:47 event0
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  65 May 18 13:47 event1
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  66 May 18 13:47 event2
```

So far, so good: I can `open("/dev/input/accelerometer0")` in my userland code and start streaming the data.  But to, for example, change the data rate, I need to write to the `pollrate_ms` attribute in the related sysfs directory. An `ls /sys/class/input/` yields:

```
event0  event1  event2  input0  input1  input2
```

I happen to know that `pollrate_ms` resides in `input0/device`, but I need to figure this out programatically, especially since future updates might cause that numbering to change.

I know that I can use `libudev` to enumerate `/sys/class/input` and then use a for loop to explore each of those directories until I find the one containing `pollrate_ms`.  It just seems like that's a lot of work compared to how easy it was to unambiguously identify the device via a udev rule.

Am I missing out on an easy way or should I just suck it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically, you could first `stat("/dev/input/accelerometer0", &stat_struct)` to find out the major and minor device numbers.

Then use `libudev`'s `udev_device_new_from_devnum()` to get a `struct udev_device` for your accelerometer, and then `udev_device_get_syspath()` to get the pathname of its sysfs directory.

Comment: This did the trick.  The resulting syspath wasn't _quite_ there but it was close enough (../device) and much easier than an enumerate for loop.